# .htaccess rewrite rule from end of path

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, uri, query-string

I need to rewrite the rule for my url according to this pattern:

Starting url :

`https://example.com/path/&param1=1&param2=2`

Destination url:

`https://example.com/file.php?param1=1&param2=2`

I therefore need to get everything that comes after the & character.

I know it's poorly formed the starting url and that the ? would be needed, but unfortunately I have this pattern to follow.
I tried this but I can't get the & character.

`RewriteRule ^path([&])$ file.php?$1 [L]`

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Do you have any existing directives in your `.htaccess` file?

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples, attempts please try following htaccess rules file. This does internal rewrite to file.php and sends query string as `param1=1&param2=2` in backend.

Also make sure your file.php and .htaccess rules file are in same path. Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/[^&]*&(\S+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ file.php?%1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there any way to write everything in the RewriteRule without the external RewriteCond?

Comment: @ghost, trust me having condition is better since we are using `THE_REQUEST` variable here which contains very first request of URI only, let me know if this helps you please?

Comment: @ghost "without the external RewriteCond?" - Is there a specific reason why you would want to avoid the use of `RewriteCond`?